# Imagemagick expand image border

Tags: imagemagick, edge-detection

I'm looking for a way in PHP Imagemagick to detect an image's edges, expand the edge area, and put a solid color behind it. Here's the input image:

[image]

And this would be the expected output:

[image]

Is this possible with Imagemagick?

Comment: Is the checkerboard area supposed to represent transparency?

Comment: Yes, the image has transparency so I put the checkerboard behind it so it wouldn't look like a solid white background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is possible - here is my approach. I am sure it could be simplified into a single command, but let's see if you like it first before I break my head thinking about it too much.

First step, as I see it, is to fill in the inner *"hole"* with black. To do that, I flatten onto a black background to make all transparent areas black, then floodfill with transparency starting at top-left corner to remove the *"outlying"* black.

```
convert -background black drop.png -flatten -fill none -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' x.png
```

[image]

Next, I need to prepare for morphology. To do that, you classically need a white shape on a black background, so let's make one of those. I flatten onto a white background, then floodfill the *"outside"* area with black. Then threshold to make the cyan coloured area go white.

```
convert -background white drop.png -flatten -fill black -draw "color 0,0 floodfill" -threshold 1% y.png
```

[image]

Now I want to do a dialtion, to expand the white area to make your border, but rather than do a dialtion and work out the difference from the original, I can use the `EdgeOut` morphology method which does exactly that. Then I invert so the white fattened areas become your black outline, and make the white areas transparent so I can overlay in the next step.

```
convert y.png -morphology edgeout disk:7 -negate -transparent white z.png
```

[image]

Now, all I need to do is composite the fattened edges onto the result of Step 1.

```
convert x.png z.png -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: This is pretty much spot-on. Is there any way to get smoother edges? I tested your commands against a few and they all look rather chunky.

Comment: Not sure how your actual images are but the ones you have posted have lots of JPEG artefacts - hopefully you are using PNGs? One option would be to replace the `-morphology edgeout disk:7` with two lots of `-morphology edgeout disk:3`. Another would be to supersample up to 4x original size before processing then resize back down to get smoothing.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that the outlines are a bit chunky, I thought about deploying a new tool to help get you smooth curves - `potrace`. Basically, it takes a black and white `PBM` (or other) format file and generates an `SVG` from it - it can also generate `EPS` files etc. so see the manpage before I undersell this amazing program. Anyway, start with my previous solution but diverge from it when you have generated the outine file `y.png` and then convert that into a black and white `PBM` file like this and have it traced to a smooth vector:

```
convert -background white z.png -flatten pbm:- | potrace -s -o curve.svg
```

You can now composite that instead of my *"slightly jaggy"* version ;-)

The vector file looks like this - there is nothing to stop you editing it and changing the fill, and/or line thickness as it is only ASCII.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="354.000000pt" height="477.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 354.000000 477.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata>
Created by potrace 1.12, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2015
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,477.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M2122 4313 c-32 -15 -290 -239 -405 -351 -117 -113 -438 -477 -502
-568 -226 -320 -268 -383 -348 -523 -38 -67 -124 -241 -170 -341 -63 -140
-138 -412 -157 -570 -19 -157 -7 -381 29 -540 30 -134 125 -358 194 -459 78
-114 268 -303 343 -341 16 -8 50 -27 76 -42 75 -43 258 -103 373 -123 98 -16
286 -17 395 -1 285 41 495 150 695 358 101 104 188 222 224 300 57 128 81 198
108 318 21 96 24 370 4 450 -22 92 -61 212 -83 260 -11 25 -27 60 -35 79 -20
47 -123 207 -202 316 -138 187 -368 530 -405 602 -33 66 -84 194 -91 230 -37
178 -43 271 -25 410 14 106 43 266 73 393 15 65 13 107 -7 129 -24 27 -49 31
-84 14z m33 -85 c-18 -83 -24 -108 -39 -183 -68 -334 -71 -447 -22 -675 11
-50 52 -157 89 -234 37 -77 141 -238 307 -476 45 -63 88 -126 98 -140 9 -14
22 -31 29 -38 7 -7 43 -59 80 -115 112 -171 170 -301 215 -487 19 -81 16 -355
-5 -450 -26 -114 -43 -165 -98 -288 -38 -82 -125 -198 -224 -297 -195 -194
-368 -281 -635 -321 -109 -16 -296 -15 -395 1 -113 19 -269 71 -343 113 -26
15 -59 33 -73 40 -68 35 -230 193 -301 293 -80 112 -170 318 -202 462 -33 143
-44 377 -26 527 17 140 79 378 127 490 9 19 22 51 30 70 107 247 278 533 491
820 49 66 50 68 137 170 224 268 443 489 660 668 22 18 54 44 70 57 17 14 32
25 34 25 2 0 0 -15 -4 -32z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ultimately, this operation will be done through the Imagemagick PHP extension, so piping imagemagick output through additional programs won't work.

Comment: You don't have to pipe it - you can just write a PBM file from IM and then call `potrace` to process it.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the binary image and create an antialised edge image with transparency using

```
convert uwtW3.png -morphology edgeout disk:7 -negate -blur 0x2 -level 50x100% \( +clone -negate \) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite edge_transparent.png
```

[image]